# I Have Error to open Second Html Page as popup window in first html page?

Tags: javascript, html

The following syntax I wrote

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Scan" language="javascript" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" /></td>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function Button1_onclick() 
{ 
     window.open("win1.html","Window1",
     "menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no");


} 

</script
```

Comment: Please use proper markup when formatting your question. Also, it might be useful to tell us what error you are getting (in Firefox, you can go to `Tools -> Error Console`). Most probably your popup is being blocked by your popup blocker.

Comment: Thnaks, Currently i am using IE

Answer (score 0):

For future purpose : don't call your function by "Return".

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Scan" language="javascript" onclick="Button1_onclick()" /></td>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function Button1_onclick() 
{ 
     window.open("win1.html","Window1",
     "menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no");


} 

</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp